# A tale of willows and oaks

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

I have a big field of mine which it’s divided from that of my neighbor by a straight line of willows and oaks. Trees of the same kind are divided by 10 and 15 other trees; this means that, for example, if tree n.1 is a willow also tree n.12 and tree n.17 will be willows, and the same holds for oaks. Given that there’s at least an oak and at least a willow, what is the maximum number of trees along my border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Confession: I got a computer to do some of the gruntwork for this answer.)

You can manage it with

> 25 trees: number from 0 and make trees 4,9,15,20 be of one type and the others of the other.

But you can't manage it with more because

> if you have any 26 consecutive trees, number them from 0 and note that 10~21~5~16~0~11~22~6~17~1~12~23~7~18~2~13~24~8~19~3~14~25~9~20~4~15 and that's all of them.

Comment: Well, I was about to come to that conclusion <sigh> ninja'd again...